# Drive Api Phone

Tags: java, android, iphone, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a java program that will create and upload excel files into a google drive. After uploading I need it to give permissions. I have done all thatbut the problem lies in trying to convert the excel files into a google files in order that people who use the sheets are able to update them with their phones. I have not been able to find any help on how to do this on the google api. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the path to your Excel file:

```
java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(excelfilepath);
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/vnd.ms-excel", fileContent);

// File's metadata.
File body = new File();
body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
body.setMimeType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

// THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART
Insert request = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent);
request.setConvert(true);
File file = request.execute();
// END OF THE IMPORTANT PART

if (file != null) {
  showToast("Data Uploaded: " + file.getTitle());
}
```